# Objective C: Accelerometer directions

Tags: objective-c, accelerometer

I'm trying to detect a shaking motion in an up and down direction like this:

```
          / \
           |
________________________________
|                              |
|                              |
|                              |
|o                             |
|                              |
|                              |
|______________________________|

           |
          \ /

-(void) bounce:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration  {
    NSLog(@"%f",acceleration.x);
}
```

I was thinking it's the x axis but that responds if you turn it to be parallel to the floor. How do I detect this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a direct answer for you, but a great experiment is to make a quick app which spews the numbers out onto the screen or into a file (or both). Then shake it the way to you want to detect, and see which set has the greatest change.